# sum multiple which statements with loop?

Tags: r, loops, shift

I'm computing a new variable in a large df in r. I wrote some code that fills my empty cells:

`data2$departure_time[which(data2$No=="3" & data2$Key=="300111")]<-data2$departure_time[which(data2$No== "2" & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$travel_time[which(data2$No=="2" & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$waiting_time[which(data2$o=="2" & data2$Key=="300111")]`

this works so far. yet i need to adapt `No`-statement in the code every time. What needs to be done is just add `1` to each `No` statement. 
So the result would be:

`data2$departure_time[which(data2$No=="4" & data2$Key=="300111")]<-data2$departure_time[which(data2$No== "3" & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$travel_time[which(data2$No=="3" & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$waiting_time[which(data2$o=="3" & data2$Key=="300111")]`

And so on..

I tried to implement a `for-loop` into my code as I thougt I would be the easiest solution. So I tried the following:

`for(in in 3:40){data2$departure_time[which(data2$No=i & data2$Key=="300111")]<-for(j in 2:40){data2$departure_time[which(data2$No= j & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$travel_time[which(data2$No= j & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$waiting_time[which(data2$No=j & data2$Key=="300111")]}}`

Unfortunately this didn't work out. I never wrote a loop in R and don't know how to solve this otherwise.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why the second `for`-loop? Can't you just do `for(i in 3:40){data2$departure_time[which(data2$No=i & data2$Key=="300111")]<-data2$departure_time[which(data2$No=i-1 & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$travel_time[which(data2$No=i-1 & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$waiting_time[which(data2$No=i-1 & data2$Key=="300111")]}`

Comment: thanks! this worked pretty well :) is there now a possibility to implement a second loop that replaces the ``Key`` Variable? I would store them in a list and nest the 2 loops?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're aiming at... You could replace the `$Key` for these rows in each loop. `for(i in 3:40){data2$departure_time[which(data2$No=i & data2$Key=="300111")]<-data2$departure_time[which(data2$No=i-1 & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$travel_time[which(data2$No=i-1 & data2$Key=="300111")] + data2$waiting_time[which(data2$No=i-1 & data2$Key=="300111")]; data2$Key[which(data2$No=i & data2$Key=="300111")]<-'Invalid'}`

Comment: Im looking for something like this:
`for(j in t){for(i in 2:40){data2$departure[which(data2$No==i & data2$Key==j)]<-data2$departuretime[which(data2$No==i-1 & data2$Key==j)] + data2$traveltime[which(data2$No==i-1 & data2$Key==j)] + data2$waitingtime[which(data2$No==i-1 & data2$Key==j)]}}`

Yet R needs ages to compute this. So Im not sure whether the code is correct